# What's wrong with my recursive procedure?

Tags: scheme

This procedure takes in a list of booleans, if it sees a false, it should terminate and return false. However the way it's running it's always true.

```
(define L3 (cons true (cons false empty)))

(check-expect (all-true? L3) false)


(define (all-true? lob)
  (cond [(empty? lob) true]
        [else 
         (if (boolean? (first lob))
         (all-true? (rest lob))
         false)]))
```

I understand that i could have used an AND clause after the else statement also.

Comment: never mind. Should have been using eq? instead of boolean?. boolean? false returns true.

Comment: No, don't use `eq?`. Just use the result of `(first lob)` directly.

Comment: Shortcut: `(define (all-true? lob) (or (empty? lob) (and (first lob) (all-true? (cdr lob)))))`

Comment: Oh yes, regarding your question: you never test if `(first lob)` is actually true or false. You just test whether it has the *type* boolean (so it can still be either, true or false).

Answer (score 3):

This should fix the problems:

```
(define (all-true? lob)
  (cond [(empty? lob) true]
        [(first lob) (all-true? (rest lob))]
        [else false]))
```

Explanation:

- If we have several nested conditions, just put them in different branches inside a `cond` instead of writing an `if` inside the `else` part of a `cond`.
- We don't want to call `boolean?`, that's for checking whether a value is *boolean*, not for determining if it's *true*.
- Given that the procedure receives a list of booleans to begin with, testing if the first element is *true* will be enough to continue the recursion

Alternatively, in Racket we can use [`andmap`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._andmap%29%29) for the same effect:

```
(define (all-true? lob)
  (andmap identity lob))
```

In other interpreters, we can import [`every`](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#every) from SRFI-1:

```
(require srfi/1)
(define (all-true? lob)
  (every (lambda (x) x) lob))
```